# knockout.js / How to respond to change event on bound dropdown list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

What should happen is the page loads, it calls the server for information about the order (at this point its just a list of possible order types and the id of the current type of the order). After the load the value of the select should be set to "selected_order_type" which it is.

However it looks like it just selecting it in the list and not actually setting the "value" of the select item to the current value. So for instance in my example it selects the 2nd option on load. If i then click the third option everything works if instead I clicked the first option first nothing happens and I am assuming it because the  still had the first options value even though it was showing the second option as the selected option. (very new to knockout been using it for a couple hours just trying to get my head around how it works).

```
<select id="order_type_select"
                    data-bind="options:order_types,
                      optionsText:'order_type',
                      optionsValue:'order_type_id',
                      value:selected_order_type"/>

function update_order_field(order_id,field,value){
    var url = '/op/update_order_field'
    data = {'order_id':order_id,'field':field,'value':value};
    console.log(url);
    console.log(data);
}

function refresh_order_data(order_id,view_model){
    $.getJSON("/op/order_json/"+order_id,function(data){
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data,view_model);
    });
    console.log(view_model.selected_order_type);
}

function OrderData(){
    var self = this;
    self.order_types = [{}]
    self.selected_order_type = '0'
    return self
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var order_id = $("#order_id").attr('order_id');
    var view_model = ko.mapping.fromJS(new OrderData());
    view_model.selected_order_type.subscribe(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
    refresh_order_data(order_id,view_model);
    ko.applyBindings(view_model);
});
```

Data coming in from server on initial load ...

```
{
    order_types: [
        { order_type_id=1, order_type="Phone"},
        { order_type_id=2, order_type="Fax"},
        {order_type_id=3, order_type="Web"}
    ],
    selected_order_type = '2' 
}
```

Comment: Verified this with some console messages. The 2nd option in the list is the one being "selected" and shown in the template as selected BUT the select is actually still sitting on the first items value.

Comment: Can you reproduce off of this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WtaLH/?  Not sure I quite understand what you are seeing.  Also make sure that you use `<select></select>` rather than `<select />`

Comment: the code on jsfiddle.net works. When i remove my getJSON from refresh_order_data and just use sample data (var initialData) in my application the system works as well. Interesting.

Comment: I just compared the result from json to "initialData" and they are identical. hmmmmmmm

Comment: Problem was server side. Although I have no idea why as the output on the client is identical. I wrapped the returning value in json.dumps using python and everything works as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was server side. Although I have no idea why as the output on the client is identical. I wrapped the returning value in json.dumps using python and everything works as intended